# Parallel For loop inside razor view in Asp MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

Just wondering how to write a parallel loop inside razor view in Asp MVC, I want something like this:

```
@Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
 {
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
 });
```

but I am unable to write Html code inside the loop.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why would you want to use `Parallel` in your Razor code? `Parallel` can be useful in case of bunch of CPU intensive calculation. When you are at the presentation layer you shouldn't do such thing. Razor is a tool to visualize your data, not to compute it.

Comment: I have many tables inside tabs, each table with hundreds of cells/rows and many conditions to show or to hide cells..., and it is taking too much time, some are taking more than 15 seconds to fully charge the page. This is why I need to use a parallel loop to save some time. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to tackle this problem? Based on the described scenario it seems to me that you want to render way more data than the consumer of your site can perceive. Would it make sense in your case to load data only on-demand (when it is really needed) not upfront?

Comment: I cannot load data on-demand in this part of the project, because after loading data, the data between tabs/tables are related, so I need to have everything loaded as soon as I can, thank you again for your return.

Comment: Why would you need to load and render all related data at once? Can consumer edit more than one side of the relationship at the same time? If only can side can be edited at once then you can update the related parties on the backend side.